# Deleting Duplicate Records from a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I Have a table called Table1 which has 48 records. Out of which only 24 should be there in that table. For some reason I got duplicate records inserted into it. How do I delete the duplicate records from that table.

Comment: If there's only 48, load up SSMS and delete them manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's something you might try if SQL Server version is 2005 or later.

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT {list-of-columns-in-table},
      row_number() over (PARTITION BY {list-of-key-columns} ORDER BY {rule-to-determine-row-to-keep}) as sequence
    FROM myTable
    )

DELETE FROM cte
WHERE sequence > 1
```

This uses a common table expression (CTE) and adds a sequence column.  {list-of-columns-in-table} is just as it states.  Not all columns are needed, but I won't explain here.

The {list-of-key-columns] is the columns that you use to define what is a duplicate.

{rule-to-determine-row-to-keep} is a sequence so that the first row is the row to keep.  For example, if you want to keep the oldest row, you would use a date column for sequence.

Here's an example of the query with real columns.

```
WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT ID, CourseName, DateAdded,
        row_number() over (PARTITION BY CourseName ORDER BY DateAdded) as sequence
    FROM Courses
    )

DELETE FROM cte
WHERE sequence > 1
```

This example removes duplicate rows based on the CoursName value and keeps the oldest basesd on the DateAdded value.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444

This section is the **key**.  The **primary** point you should take away.  ;)

> This article discusses how to locate
>   and remove duplicate primary keys from
>   a table. However, you should closely
>   examine the process which allowed the
>   duplicates to happen in order to
>   prevent a recurrence.

Identify your records by grouping data by your logical keys, since you obviously haven't defined them, and applying a HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 statement at the end.  The article goes into this in depth.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easier way

```
Select * Into #TempTable FROM  YourTable
Truncate Table YourTable
Insert into YourTable Select Distinct * from #TempTable
Drop Table #TempTable
```

Comment: If this does not work then it means they are not exactly duplicate as the distinct would eliminate the duplicates, are you using a primary key?

Comment: I am not using primary key but I have a column called id which is of identity